# How to suggest a FAQ?

Tags: discussion

As a part of the cleanup week I see a FAQ - "How to completely remove a program and it's configuration files?"

As a part of clean up, this question

[How to fully remove the eclipse package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81761/how-to-fully-remove-a-package)
could possibly be merged with these two

[How to remove unwanted configuration files/folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105627/how-to-remove-unwanted-configuration-files-folders)

and [How to remove configuration files completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely)

What is the best method of communicating this ? Listing them in meta or flagging them ?

Comment: The system [calculates these FAQs based](http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=faq) upon views, votes and how many duplicates it has - so in otherwords, you can't suggest it. However, if you're talking about duplicates that should be merged, flag them.

Comment: OK, I will flag them as duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system [calculates these FAQs based](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=faq) upon views, votes and how many duplicates it has - so in otherwords, you can't suggest it.

However, if you're talking about duplicates that should be merged, flag them, and a moderator will merge them if necessary.